# Webservice Client can not reuse existing https connection

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have the following issue.

I have a Weblogic 12.2.1 application server in which my application is installed. The application has a proccess that is executed daily. This process has to create a SOAP Webservice Client and call a Webservice. Multiple calls to the Webservice server are needed in order to complete the proccess. The Webservice Server is an apache tomcat (I don't know the exact version). Both the Client and the Server use apache CXF version 2.7.11. Between the Server and the client there is an apache proxy, so calls from the client to the server are made through the proxy. https is used.

The first operation call is always successful. The second crashes with the following Stacktrace:

```
2016-05-12 16:32:11,054 WARN : cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.pharmnet_bund.de/services/pnpartnerinformation}PnPartnerinformationService#{http://www.pharmnet_bund.de/services/pnpartnerinformation}fetchPartnerById has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362.fetchPartnerById(Unknown Source)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient.updatePartnerInformationServiceLegacy(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:361)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient.access$400(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:60)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient$1.run(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:612)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:240)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$SingleBufferWrite.writeTo(NIOOutputStream.java:841)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.flush(NIOOutputStream.java:455)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.write(NIOOutputStream.java:334)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.write(NIOOutputStream.java:220)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:876)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:847)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkOutputStream.flush(HttpChunkOutputStream.java:213)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkOutputStream.write(HttpChunkOutputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.write(UTF8XmlOutput.java:396)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.beginStartTag(UTF8XmlOutput.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:324)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1052)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1031)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    ... 19 more
2016-05-12 16:32:11,056 ERROR: ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient - Call to method fetchPartnerById was not successfull.
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Marshalling Error: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362.fetchPartnerById(Unknown Source)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient.updatePartnerInformationServiceLegacy(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:361)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient.access$400(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:60)
    at de.bfarm.amanda.web.ws.clients.PnPartnerInformationClient$1.run(PnPartnerInformationClient.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:612)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:240)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$SingleBufferWrite.writeTo(NIOOutputStream.java:841)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.flush(NIOOutputStream.java:455)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.write(NIOOutputStream.java:334)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.write(NIOOutputStream.java:220)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:876)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:847)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkOutputStream.flush(HttpChunkOutputStream.java:213)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkOutputStream.write(HttpChunkOutputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.write(UTF8XmlOutput.java:396)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.beginStartTag(UTF8XmlOutput.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:324)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1052)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1031)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    ... 19 more
```

So far I have obtained this information:
1. When http is used instead of https it works perfectly.
2. When in the apache proxy server the configuration "KeepAlive off" is set then it also works perfectly.
3. When in the apache proxy server the configuration "KeepAlive on" is set and I instruct the client to not use keep alives (http header keep-alive: close) then it also works perfectly.
4. Recently we updated the weblogic server from version 12.1.2 to 12.2.1. With 12.1.2 it worked fine. With 12.2.1 these problems started.

Anybody has any idea what is going on? Is there a way o make this work with keep alive working? Any additional information that is needed by me please ask. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about an standalone client outside WebLogic?

Comment: This make sense, but the process takes advantage of some other j2ee goodies as well. There is access to the database through JPA for instance. Changing to a standalone client would require a lot of effort. I can tell that the client uses Weblogic libraries during the calls. If there could be a way to create the client within weblogic and to run it withouth using any weblogic classes that could probably solve the issue. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Seems the connection pool used by Weblogic 12.2.1 HTTP client when it is keeping connections alive is broken such that it tries to use connections that have been closed by the server. The workaround should be do not use weblogic output streams, but i do not know how to disable this behaviour on weblogic